# Java, Android, camerax programming. Error: MediaRecorder ERROR_SERVER_DIED (Error:8)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-camerax

I have this class which opens the Camera with CameraX together with a face detection. When I start the camera, the face detetction is working and I can click on my button "id:capture", which starts the recording. After clicking on it again, the recording stops and I get the error  ERROR_SERVER_DIED (Error:8), the video will not be saved on my device.

This is the part of my Code,  the problem is in

```
public void captureVideo()
```

I added some logs, the video recording does start, but it does not safe the video. Is there a problem with using the preview for the face detection and the recording? Thank you for your help in advance!

```
public class FaceDetection extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis1;
    VideoCapture<Recorder> videoCapture = null;
    private boolean isCameraInitialized = false; // Declare isCameraInitialized here
    int cameraFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
    ImageButton capture;
    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider; // Declare cameraProvider here
    PreviewView previewView;
    private Preview preview;
    private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis;
    private DrawLayerAroundFace drawLayerAroundFace;
    Recording recording = null;
    private ImageAnalysis previewImageAnalysis;
    private ImageAnalysis recordingImageAnalysis;

    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
private RelativeLayout rootview; 
private TextView textView; 
private boolean isRecording = false;
private BaseImage baseImageInstance;

private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 1;
private Handler handler;
CameraSelector cameraSelector; 

private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), result -> {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FaceDetection.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         startCamera(cameraFacing);
    }
});


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detection);



    // Initialize the DrawLayerAroundFace with the current activity and an empty bounding box
    drawLayerAroundFace = new DrawLayerAroundFace(this);

    previewView = findViewById(R.id.pv);

    // Initialize the TextToSpeech instance
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, status -> {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // TextToSpeech initialisierung erfolgreich
        } else {
            // TextToSpeech could not be initillized
        }
    });
    // Initialize the rootview using the correct ID
    rootview = findViewById(R.id.conlay);

    // Initialize the textView using the correct ID
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView3);

// Pass the Context reference to the BaseImage constructor // Initialize the imageAnalysis1 variable imageAnalysis1 = new ImageAnalysis.Builder() .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST) .setTargetResolution(new Size(900, 1200)) .build();    // Pass the Context reference to the BaseImage constructor
    BaseImage baseImage = new BaseImage(this, textToSpeech, rootview, textView);

    // Set the BaseImage instance as the analyzer for the ImageAnalysis
    imageAnalysis1.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), baseImage);


    renderImage();



    baseImageInstance = new BaseImage(this, textToSpeech, rootview, textView);

    ImageButton startCameraButton = findViewById(R.id.capture);
    startCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check camera permission and start the camera
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FaceDetection.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                activityResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            } else {
                startCamera(cameraFacing);
            }
        }
    });

    capture = findViewById(R.id.capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        // Check camera permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FaceDetection.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            activityResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        // Check audio recording permission
        else if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FaceDetection.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            activityResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
        // Check write storage permission for Android versions <= P
        else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FaceDetection.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            activityResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        // Start video capture
        else {
            captureVideo();
        }
    });

    // Check camera permission and start the camera


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(FaceDetection.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        activityResultLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    } else {
        startCamera(cameraFacing);
    }


    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}

// Call this method when you want to start video recording
public void captureVideo() {
    capture.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_stop_circle_24);
    Recording recording1 = recording;
    if (recording1 != null) {
        // Stop ongoing recording
        recording1.stop();
        recording = null;
        return;
    }

    // Generate file name for the captured video
    String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS", Locale.getDefault()).format(System.currentTimeMillis());

    // Prepare media store output options for video capture
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/CameraX-Video");
    MediaStoreOutputOptions options = new MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(getContentResolver(), MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            .setContentValues(contentValues).build();

    // Check audio recording permission
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    // Start video recording
    recording = videoCapture.getOutput().prepareRecording(FaceDetection.this, options).withAudioEnabled().start(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(FaceDetection.this), videoRecordEvent -> {
        if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start) {
            capture.setEnabled(true);
            // Video recording started
            Log.d("VideoRecording", "Video recording started");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Video recording started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) {
            if (!((VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent).hasError()) {
                String msg = "Video erfolgreich aufgezeichnet: " + ((VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent).getOutputResults().getOutputUri();
                Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Video recording completed successfully
                Log.d("VideoRecording", "Video recording completed successfully");
            } else {
                int errorCode = ((VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent).getError();
                if (errorCode == 8) {
                    // Fehlercode 8 entspricht dem "ERROR_SERVER_DIED"-Fehler
                    // MediaRecorder zurücksetzen und neu initialisieren
                    if (recording != null) {
                        recording.close();
                        recording = null;
                    }
                    // Beispiel: mediaRecorder.reset(); mediaRecorder.release(); initializeMediaRecorder();
                    Log.e("VideoRecording", "MediaRecorder ERROR_SERVER_DIED");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error: MediaRecorder ERROR_SERVER_DIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (recording != null) { // Check if 'recording' is null before calling close()
                        recording.close();
                        recording = null;
                    }
                    String msg = "Error: " + errorCode;
                    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Other errors occurred during video recording
                    Log.e("VideoRecording", "Error during video recording: " + errorCode);
                }
            }
            capture.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_fiber_manual_record_24);
            // After stopping the recording, start the NotesActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(FaceDetection.this, NotesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}





private void startCamera(int cameraFacing) {
    ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

            // Set up preview
            Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

            // Set up video capture
            Recorder recorder = new Recorder.Builder()
                    .setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST))
                    .build();
            videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder);

            // Initialize the previewImageAnalysis
            previewImageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .setTargetResolution(new Size(900, 1200))
                    .build();

            // Create an instance of BaseImage to perform face detection for preview
            BaseImage baseImage = new BaseImage(this, textToSpeech, rootview, textView);

            // Set the BaseImage instance as the analyzer for the previewImageAnalysis
            previewImageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), baseImage);

            // Bind preview use cases to the camera lifecycle
            cameraProvider.unbindAll();
            cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(cameraFacing).build();
            Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, previewImageAnalysis);

            // Camera for preview is now initialized
            isCameraInitialized = true;
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
}






private void renderImage() {
    ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> val = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

    val.addListener(() -> {
        try {
            ProcessCameraProvider processCameraProvider = val.get();
            preview = new Preview.Builder().setTargetResolution(new Size(900, 1200)).build();

            CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT).build();

            preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

            ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY).build();
            ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis1 = new ImageAnalysis.Builder().setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                    .setTargetResolution(new Size(900, 1200)).build();

            // Create an instance of BaseImage to perform face detection
            BaseImage baseImage = new BaseImage(this, textToSpeech, rootview, textView);

            // Set the BaseImage instance as the analyzer for the ImageAnalysis
            imageAnalysis1.setAnalyzer(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), baseImage);

            // Bind all use cases to the camera lifecycle
            processCameraProvider.unbindAll();
            Camera camera = processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalysis1);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
}



}
```

Comment: So it's a problem related to the camera rather than Firebase, right?

Comment: I think it could be both, because when using only the camera function, it works but with the face detection it does not anymore, the video gets corrupted or I get the error:8

Comment: I would recommend checking out the `LifecycelCameraController` API, it handles some of the recording logic for you so there is less chance for you to make a mistake. Also not sure how you plan to do the face detection but if you are using MLKit, there is `MLKitAnalyzer`.  I noticed there is a `recordingImageAnalysis` too but unused. Just FYI CameraX only supports one ImageAnalysis instance.